# Bootstrap Modal in separate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I've recently faced the following problem: When I am trying to embed this jquery code in html page, everything works perfectly fine. However, when I put the same 3 lines of code in a separate js file, it doesnt work! Am I doing something wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
       $(window).load(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You must include the separate js file after you include the jquery library because you are using jquery functions and they must be loaded first.

Comment: You must first include the jquery library, then the bootstrap.min.js, and then your custom js file.